# 3-4 months stay in UK on visitor visa

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, long-term

I live in the UK and over the last 10 or so years I have had relatives from various countries visit me here for duration of up to a month or so on a standard 6-month visitor visa. I know that (notionally at least) if you end up staying in the UK for a rather long period, say 3-4 months, while technically legal, may cause issues in the future when applying for a new visa.

Presently my 18 year old niece, who just finished school, wants to visit us in the UK for 3 months or so. She doesn't intend to work or study; she wants to simply spend time in the UK to improve her English in native speaking country. She would live with us would probably help with childcare occasionally (i.e. babysitting once in a while - but as a family member, without pay). She has no intention of staying in the UK and no reason to want to. She has travelled extensively abroad and has numerous Schengen visas in her passport. In fact, her grandparents are Norwegian citizens and she is considering moving to Norway longer term. Yet, she hasn't visited the UK before.

My question is two-fold. First, is a standard 6-month visitor visa the right approach or is there a better type visa for this purpose? She does not qualify for young migrant programme. Second, if she does apply for a visitor visa, what's the best approach to this?

**Updated**

Thanks for the replies so far. The nationality is an obvious question. My niece is a Russian citizen living in Russia. She is not eligible for Norwegian citizenship by default, as both her parents are Russian citizens born in Russia. Grandparents are settled Norwegian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention the nationality of your niece. She can apply for a visit visa but it will be difficult to convince the visa officer that she will leave the country before her visa ends, keeping in mind she is 18 and has recently finished school.
But if you are willing to sponsor her complete stay then its worth a try to apply on her behalf. Guess you will need to show your bank statements, payslips etc that you can afford to keep her for the whole duration of her stay.

Just follow a visitor visa route and make sure you follow the checklist, simple.

Comment: I have more than enough experience with visas and stuff, thank you for your comment though. If you are aware of visas then you must know it depends heavily on individual cases. So giving generalised information might not be useful to one particular applicant. That is why there is an element of uncertainty.

Comment: I joined recently as I was not aware of this forum. And this username is my real name, am not aware if someone else is also using it. The system shouldn't have allowed me to take it or should have asked me to choose a different one. Have a good day!

Comment: User names aren't required to be unique on this site. Probably because it allows people to post using their real names. [The other Ali Awan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/43993/ali-awan) has a distinctively different user icon, so there's not going to be any real confusion. Welcome to the site!